# PHP filter validate int issue when first character is 0

Tags: php, validation, filter-var

I am using the PHP `filter_validate_int` to perform a simple telephone validation. The length should be exactly 10 chars and all should be numeric. However as most of the telephone numbers start with a 0. The filter validate int function return false. Is there anyway to resolve this issue. Here is the code that I have used

```
if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || strlen($value) != 10) return false;
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have `filter_validate_int` function. Can you show us the code of that function.

Comment: @Glavić I updated my question. Sorry I meant to mention that I use the filter var function.

Comment: Just a note: In the US it is not possible for an area code to begin with a 0 so a phone number can not start with a zero. So your validation routine would work fine for US only numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing you can do to make this validation work. In any case, you should not be using `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` because telephone numbers are not integers; they are *strings of digits*.

If you want to make sure that `$tel` is a string consisting of exactly 10 digits you can use a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $tel)) // it's valid
```

or (perhaps better) some oldschool string functions:

```
if (strlen($tel) == 10 && ctype_digit($tel)) // it's valid
```

Comment: So this means that I can't use the FILTER_VALIDATE_INT function, if there could be values starting from 0. I am asking this because I am using that for another validation as well. I used it for another validation specially due to the fact that it validates min and max ranges too. And in your answer you have mention ctype_digit is it an equivalent to is_numeric.

Comment: @crazyMAN: Yes, `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` does not allow leading zeroes and it also does not allow values larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`. `is_numeric` is much less strict than `ctype_digit` because it allows signs, decimal point and exponential notation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$str = '0123456789';

if(preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $str))
{
    echo "valid";
} 
else 
{
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex :

```
if (!preg_match('~^\d{10}$~', $value)) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a PHP bug - [#43372](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43372)

Regex are fine, but consume some resources.

**This works fine with any integer, including zero and leading zeros**

```
if (filter_var(ltrim($val, '0'), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === 0) {
    echo("Variable is an integer");
} else {
    echo("Variable is not an integer");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution, not an "you cant do this" :)

Answer (score -1):

0 is not a valid starting number for an int. 0 is the starting number of octal numbers.

A telephone number is a string, not an int. You have to use a regexp to validate it.

Comment: The octal reference is a red herring. That's not the problem here; the problem is that the validator expects `(string)(int)$str` to be exactly equal to `(string)$str`.

Comment: @Jon you're not correct in that (more precise, not fully correct, I think). You can pass `['flags'=>FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL]` to `filter_var` as a third parameter, and, if string will be a valid oct - that will work (but if it contains `8` or `9` - will not)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: I know, but there is no allow octal flag here.

Comment: The problem isn't that it's octal or not of course. I was merely pointing him out the misconception he had about integers. "That's not because it looks like a series of digits that it's an int".

Comment: @Jon but so (if string would not contain `8` or `9`) that could be an option to resolve a matter via `filter_var` (so that's you're not fully correct that _oct_ numbers have nothing to do with this case)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: No, it's still not an option. `"01234"` does not validate.

Comment: @Jon because of length? OP is checking it separately.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: No, because of what I wrote on the first comment above.

Comment: @Jon sorry, did not get your point. `01234` have length 5 and will not pass. but if you'll pass `0123412341` - that will work (it's correct oct number & it's length as a string is 10)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: Why don't you try it and see what happens? I would appreciate it if you checked your facts first.

Comment: @Jon so do you. See [this fiddle](http://3v4l.org/g9GfP) - it returns `false` (i.e. OP's filter for _invalid_ values will return false - and so, string _is valid_). Of cause, if you'll put `8` or `9`, situation will change.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: Why do you keep bringing `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL` into the discussion? **We are talking about phone numbers**.

Comment: @Jon I'm not bringing that. My oppinion is - to disagree with point, that oct have nothing to do with this _at all_. They may be used. Anyway, _I agree_ with that fact, that leading zeros are causing wrong result because of `(int)` cast. And, therefore, if there will be more than 1 leading zero, filter will fail anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to check whether the return is false or 0. The filters return the input when the validation is successful, or false when it fails.

Use strict comparison (=== or !==) for the comparison, like $result!==false.

```
if(filter_var($squid, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)!==false ) {
 //if it's here, it passed validation
}
```

You could also use the is_numeric function: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php